# Why is my windows form falling back to the Dispose method when it hasn't been instructed to?

Tags: c#, dialog, stack-trace, dispose

I have a windows forms application that opens a dialog box to accept a preference setting.

The code to open the dialog box is as follows:

```
    private void HandleOutputBufferSetting(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.BufferEditor.Visible)
            return;
        else
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
                this.Invoke(new Action(delegate { this.HandleOutputBufferSetting(sender, e); }));
            else
            {
                this.ShowBufferSizeEditor();
                return;
            }
    }

    protected void ShowBufferSizeEditor()
    {
        if (this.BufferEditor == null)
        {
            this.BufferEditor = new BufferSizeEditor();
            this.ShowBufferSizeEditor();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.BufferEditor.Visible)
            {
                throw new Exception("The Buffer Editor cannot be shown as it is already visible.");
            }
            else
            {
                this.BufferEditor.ShowDialog(this);

                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

The execution of all of the above code completes successfully - but upon closing the aforementioned dialog box, the program begins disposal of the dialog boxes parent window; code for which is automatically generated by the Visual Studio designer, and is as follows:

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

The stack trace at this point of execution indicates that a segment of external code initialized the Main method I've crafted, followed by an execution of another external method, followed by this disposal.

If anyone has any suggestions as to what might be causing this I am sure I would be appreciative.

The code inside and around the Main method is as follows:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new UndisclosedObjectType());
    }
```

Comment: If nobody has any resolution for this issue I'll be posting a bounty in roughly 23 hours in order to attempt to find a resolution.

Comment: Where is this code (you mentioned above) written? on main Form? Is there some code running in `BufferSizeEditor` form, which is causing its parent form to be closed? Plus the way you are creating the new instance of `BufferSizeEditor` i.e. recursive call, is also confusing. Your event handler `HandleOutputBufferSetting` seems to be handling the multi-threaded call, but at the same time you are accessing the control's `Visible` property prior to `Invoke`, I am NOT sure this is a valid approach.

Comment: Pretty normal, Dispose() runs after the form is closed.  If you want to find out why then add the FormClosing event handler and set a breakpoint on it.

Comment: can you show codes of the windows form related to ShowBufferSizeEditor()?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can think of, the only reason for the Dialog to be disposed other than manually is either because:

- The owner for the owner object that you passed as argument "this" in the ShowDialog() call is no longer existing. A dialog will dispose itself if its owner is disposed.
- There are for any reason no references pointing TO the dialog in memory at one point and Carbage Collector disposed the dialog, this may happen because the object from which the reference to the dialog's is kept is destroyed. (The BufferSizeEditor)

I think example 2 is almost impossible, since a reference to the dialog is kept as a child of its owner component. Unless you would be messing with this.

Answer (score 0):

refer [Implementing a Dispose Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

A protected virtual (Overridable in Visual Basic) Dispose method whose signature is:

The `disposing` parameter is a *Boolean* that indicates whether the method call comes from a *Dispose method* (its value is **true**) or from a *finalizer* (its value is **false**).

The body of the method consists of two blocks of code:

A block that **frees unmanaged resources**. This block executes **regardless** of the value of the disposing parameter.

A **conditional block** that **frees managed resources**. This block executes if the value of *disposing* is **true**. The *managed resources* that it frees can include:

**Managed objects that implement `T:System.IDisposable.`**

The conditional block can be used to call **their Dispose implementation**. If you have used a safe handle to wrap your unmanaged resource, you should call the **SafeHandle.Dispose(Boolean)** implementation here.

**Managed objects that consume large amounts of memory or consume scarce resources.**

Freeing these objects explicitly in the **Dispose method** releases them **faster** than if they were reclaimed non-deterministically by the garbage collector.

If the method call comes from a **finalizer** (that is, if `disposing` is *false*), only the code that **frees unmanaged resources** executes. Because the order in which the garbage collector destroys managed objects during finalization is **not defined**, this **prevents** the finalizer from trying to **release managed resources** that **may have already been reclaimed**.

---

### Conclusion

Refer to [Form.ShowDialog Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx)

> Because a form displayed as a dialog box is hidden instead of closed,
>   you must call the Dispose method of the form when the form is no
>   longer needed by your application.

so even a protected virtual Dispose method is called,
but it only free unmanaged resources of `BufferEditor` but not the managed resource if `disposing` is *false*. To really dispose your dialog box, you need `BufferEditor.Dispose();`

Answer (score -1):

The code

```
ShowDialog(this);
```

opens a form as a subcontext of the current running thread. After loosing focus to this form, the windows automatically runs Dispose.
To stop that, you have to change ti to

```
Show();
```

and

```
Hide();
```